# Mathematical notion

Tags: education

I have the following equation:

> [image: original code]

Then I use the code in R - a mathematical program:

> [image: codeInR]

This gives me these results:

> [image: MyResults]

But the right results are:

> [image: TheRightResults]

Can anybody help point me in the right direction - I have tried moveing around with the paranthesis to no avail. Thanks in advance

Comment: try parenthesis: (2 * FT3)

Comment: Need (2*FT3) in the denominator

Comment: Thanks to both of you - it solved my problem - How do I credit you?